# Responsive carousel - a different approach

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel

I am currently creating a carousel so a developer only has to insert a unorder-list into the page. The JS will then wrap UL with the relevant divs for the carousel to work. There is a few reasons why I have decided to approach it in this manner:

Firstly; easy for all developers to just copy and paste ULs into page;
Secondly; Eventually by using data attributes, a developer will be able to determine at what breakpoint the carousel will kick in. For example on Desktop, there will be no carousel, just 4 images laid out in a grid formation, but by using a data attr such as 'data-carousel="720"' the carousel will kick in at 720px.

Now I have it kind of working. Im getting the carousel wrapper to wrap and unwrap depending on the breakpoint. I am also getting the carousel to begin when it hits the breakpoint, however, when I go back to desktop I can not for the life of me, remove the function that is applying the carousel. Can someone please help.

This is the init script

```
$(function(){

  function doneResizing() {

    var width = $(window).width();
        //getDataAttr = $car.data('carousel');

    if (width <=767) {
      carousel.createWrap();
      carousel.beginCarousel();
    } else {
      carousel.removeWrap();
      carousel.destroyCarousel();
    }
  }

  var id;

  $(window).on('load resize orientationchange', function() {  

    clearTimeout(id);
    id = setTimeout(doneResizing, 500);
  });

});
```

This is the main script

```
var carousel = (function() {

  var test;

  return {

    createWrap: function() {
      var $carContainer = $('<div class="carousel-container" />')
          $carViewer = $('<div class="carousel-viewer" />'),
          $carBtnWrap = $('<div class="carousel-buttons" />'),
          $carBtnUl = $('<ul />');

      $carContainer.append($carViewer, $carBtnWrap);
      $carBtnWrap.append($carBtnUl);

      $('.carousel').wrap($carContainer);

    },

    removeWrap: function() {
      $('.carousel-container .carousel-viewer').unwrap();
      $('.carousel-viewer .carousel-group').unwrap();
      $('.carousel-viewer .carousel').unwrap();
      $('.carousel-buttons').remove();
    },

    beginCarousel: function() {
      $('.carousel-container').each(function() {
        var $this = $(this),
            $group = $this.find('.carousel'),
            $slides = $this.find('li'),
            buttonArray = [],
            currentIndex = 0,
            timeout;

        function move (newIndex) {
          var animateLeft,
              animateRight;

          advance();

          if ($group.is(':animated' || currentIndex === newIndex)) {
            return;
          }

          buttonArray[currentIndex].removeClass('active');
          buttonArray[newIndex].addClass('active');

          if (newIndex > currentIndex) {
            slideLeft = '100%';
            animateLeft= '-100%';
          } else {
            slideLeft = '-100%';
            animateLeft = '100%';
          }

          $slides.eq(newIndex).css({
            left: slideLeft,
            display: 'block'
          });

          $group.animate({
            left: animateLeft
          }, function () {
                $slides.eq(currentIndex).css({
                  display: 'none'
                });

                $slides.eq(newIndex).css({
                  left: 0
                });

                $group.css({
                  left: 0
                });

                currentIndex = newIndex;
          });
        }


        function advance () {
          clearTimeout(timeout);

          timeout = setTimeout(function() {
            if (currentIndex < ($slides.length - 1)) {
              move(currentIndex + 1);
            } else {
              move(0);
            }
          }, 5000);
        }

        $.each($slides, function(index) {
          var $buttonWrap = $('.carousel-buttons ul'),
              $buttonLi = $('<li />'),
              $button = $('<a href="">&bull;</a>');

          $button.appendTo($buttonLi);

          $buttonLi.appendTo($buttonWrap);

          if (index === currentIndex) {
            $button.addClass('active');
          }

          $button.on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            move(index);
          });
            buttonArray.push($button);
        });

        advance();
      });

    },

    destroyCarousel: function() {

    }
  };

}());
```

Can anyone help, am I approaching this the right way?

Comment: *"...data attr such as 'data-carousel="720"' the carousel will kick in at 720px."* - That is typically a decision I don't want to make in my markup.